# How to select the first and the last record base on time-sequence in hive?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a hive table of two columns. The first columns is time, and second is scattered objects. I wish to get all groups of same objects which are continuous in time, and pick up the first and last record. How to achieve this in hive?

For example, I have a table like this:

```
id   time      object
1   10:01:00   a
2   10:02:00   a
3   10:03:00   a
4   10:04:00   b
5   10:05:00   b
6   10:06:00   a
7   10:07:00   a
8   10:08:00   a
9   10:09:00   a
10  10:10:00   a
11  10:11:00   c
```

I wish to get this (as object 'a' is continuous from 10:01:00 to 10:03:00 and from 10:06:00 to 10:10:00, so both line1&line3 and line6&line10 are picked up):

```
id   time      object
1   10:01:00   a
3   10:03:00   a
4   10:04:00   b
5   10:05:00   b
6   10:06:00   a
10  10:10:00   a
11  10:11:00   c
```

What should I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is island and gap problem and you can use the row_number analytical function as follows:

```
select * from
(select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by rn-rn_o order by time) as rn,
       row_number() over (partition by rn-rn_o order by time desc) as rn_d
  from
(select t.*,
       row_number() over (order by time) as rn,
       row_number() over (partition by object order by time) as rn_o
  from your_table t) t)
where 1 in (rn, rn_d);
```

Comment: Thanks very much! But I think the third and forth line should be "row_number() over (partition by object, rn-rn_o order by time)" otherwise there is a chance that different object share the same rn-rn_o which leads to wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the rows which are not equal to the previous row, or not equal to the next row, using `lag` and `lead` respectively. Also a check for first/last row is needed to include them.

```
select id, time, object from 
(select *,
    (lead(object) over (order by time) != object or row_number() over (order by time desc) = 1) cond1, 
    (lag(object) over (order by time) != object or row_number() over (order by time) = 1) cond2
from table)
where cond1 or cond2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this as a gaps-and-islands problem.  You seem to want only the rows where there is a change.  This suggests a simple application of `lag()` and `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(object) over (order by time) as prev_object,
             lead(object) over (order by time) as next_object
      from t
     ) t
where (prev_object is null or prev_object <> object) or
      (next_object is null or next_object <> object);
```

Hive supports the `NULL`-safe comparison operator, so you can phrase the `where` as:

```
where not (prev_object <=> object) or
      not (next_object <=> object)
```